# How to install java package on mac

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

My app requires an extension package, specifically in this case: *jfreechart* 
So I download it and extract it. I created a Classpath to it:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/Lacie/Desktop/project"
```

But after that, I run my program on terminal and it returns:

```
error: package org.jfree.chart does not exist
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
```

How do I install the java package or create the Classpath?
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I am not familiar with what you are trying to do, but usually you have to add the file to your project and then import it to the class that you are trying to use it in.   http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44 maybe that link will help.

Comment: I do not think there is anything *mac* specific about this.  You simply need to add the `jar` to your project and your classpath